# Radio button adding class element

Tags: jquery, html, css, radio-button

I need to create 2 radio buttons.

When a users is on the page, the radio buttons are unchecked.
Inside radio button content is the CTA button which will be greyed
The CTA button will change the color only when the user selects the radio.

I have created style for the button which I want to use rather switch back and forth when the radio button is selected.

Here's an example.
Can someone guide me on how to add and remove classes so the colors switch within jQuery?

https://codepen.io/Ambuja/pen/BZNzRx

```js
$('input').prop('checked', false);
$('span a').css('background-color','grey')
$('input').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var dt = $(this).data('title')
        $('span a').css('background-color','grey')
        $('#' + dt).css('background-color','orange')
        console.log(dt)
    }
})
```

```css
label {
    font-family: $verdana;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-left:13px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
 
 
 
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
 
    text-align: center;
}
.high {
    color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-6 large-6 columns">
    <input type="radio" name="form-radio" id="workshops" value="high" data-title="workshopcl" checked="">
    <label id="workshoping" for="workshops">Workshops</label>

    <p>This is random text</p>

    <span style="
    background-color: grey;
"><a href="#" id="workshopcl" style="background-color: orange;">WorkShops</a></span>
  </div>

  <div class="medium-6 large-6 columns">
    <input type="radio" name="form-radio" id="courses" data-title="cou" value="option2">
    <label for="courses">Courses</label>
    <br>
    <p>This is a random text</p>



    <span><a href="#" id="cou" class="" style="background-color: transparent;">Courses</a></span>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You can use removeClass and addClass. Alternatively, there is the jquery UI plug-in which includes switchClass (http://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('input').prop('checked', false);
$('span a').addClass('greyColor');
$('input').on('change', function (el) {
  debugger;
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var dt = $(this).data('title');
        //if you have only 2 radio btn, you could use the below commented code.

        //if(dt=="cou"){
          //  $('#cou').attr('href','https://www.google.com');
          //  $('#cou').addClass('orangeColor');
          //  $('#workshopcl').removeClass('orangeColor');
          //  $('#workshopcl').attr('href','#');
        //}
        //else{
          //  $('#workshopcl').addClass('orangeColor');
          //  $('#workshopcl').attr('href','https://www.gmail.com');
          //  $('#cou').removeClass('orangeColor');
          //  $('#cou').attr('href','#');
//        }


        $('span a').removeClass('orangeColor');
        $('#' + dt).addClass('orangeColor');
        $('span a').attr('href','#');
        if(dt=="cou"){
            $('#' + dt).attr('href','https://www.google.com');
        }
        else{ // if you have more than 2 radio buttons then use if-else-if statement.
            $('#' + dt).attr('href','https://www.gmail.com');
        }
    }
})
```

```css
label {
    font-family: $verdana;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-left:13px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
 
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
 
    text-align: center;
}
.high {
    color:yellow;
}

.greyColor{
  background-color:grey;
}

.orangeColor{
  background-color:orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-6 large-6 columns">
    <input type="radio" name="form-radio" id="workshops" value="high" data-title="workshopcl" checked="">
<label id="workshoping" for="workshops">Workshops</label>
 
                       <p>This is random text</p>

       <span><a href="#" id="workshopcl">WorkShops</a></span>
                        </div>
 
  <div class="medium-6 large-6 columns">
<input type="radio" name="form-radio" id="courses" data-title="cou" value="option2">
<label for="courses">Courses</label>
<br>
<p>This is a random text</p>

 
             
                        <span><a href="#" id="cou">Courses</a></span>
                       
                        </div>
                       
  </div>
```

Comment: So once the CTA button is highlighted to orange a link needs to be added to the CTA how can I achieve this ?

Comment: @code21 I have updated the code to add link once selecting the radio button.

Comment: Thank you pawan , appreciate it , I am learning as I am doing stuff

Comment: That's the only approach to learn :) 
As you are new to stackoverflow, so my suggestion is accept the most appropriate answer and do upvote for every answer which helps you.

Comment: I agree, in your code the  link is just "google.com" what if I need to add 2 different urls for the orange links

Comment: I have updated the code. You should add all your requirements in the question itself so that who ever refer it, can see the exact ques.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the jQuery methods `removeClass()` and `addClass()`.

Often when you want to remove an active class from a group of elements and apply the active class to a new one you remove the active class from all elements in the group first, then add the class to selected element. Though we'll do it a little different this time because there's additional markup complexity and a `data-` attribute we can hook into.

With this solution I took advantage of the fact that your `data-title` attribute contained the ID value of the associated anchor. On each change on an `input` we remove the active class from the stored anchor in `$active`, then use the value of `data-title` to select the associated anchor and apply the active class.

***Note: Made some improvements to your markup (HTML).*

```js
var $active;

$( 'input' ).on( 'change', function ( e ) {
  
  var $this = $( this ),
      ctaID = $this.data( 'title' );
      
  if ( $active ) $active.removeClass( 'active' );
  
  $active = $( '#' + ctaID ).addClass( 'active' );

} );
```

```css
label {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.cta {
  background-color: gray;
}
.active {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">

  <div class="medium-6 large-6 columns">
  
    <label id="workshoping" for="workshops">
      <input id="workshops" class="radio" type="radio" name="form-radio" value="high" data-title="workshopcl">
      Workshops
    </label>
    <p>This is random text</p>
    <a href="#" id="workshopcl" class="cta">WorkShops</a>
    
  </div>

  <div class="medium-6 large-6 columns">
  
    <label for="courses">
      <input id="courses" class="radio" type="radio" name="form-radio" data-title="cou" value="option2">
      Courses
    </label>
    <p>This is a random text</p>
    <a href="#" id="cou" class="cta">Courses</a>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you , I think this is what I am looking for :)